# Alert appears too early

Tags: javascript

This is my code in JavaScript:

```
$("#bot1Selected").attr("card-value", botPick.value + botPick.suit.substring(0, 1));
$("#bot1Selected").css("background-image", "url('images/cards/" + checkValue(botPick.value) + botPick.suit.substring(0, 1) + ".png')");


$("#player1Selected").attr("card-value", playerDisplay);
$("#player1Selected").css("background-image", "url('images/cards/" + checkValue(playerDisplay.slice(0, -1)) + playerDisplay[playerDisplay.length - 1] + ".png')");

if (playerVal.value > botPick.value) {
    //sleep(500);
    alert("Your Card is Higher");
} else {
    //sleep(500);
    alert("Bot's Card is Higher");
}

if (playerVal.value > botPick.value) {
    endTurn(playerDiscard, [playerVal, botPick]);
} else {
    endTurn(bot1Discard, [playerVal, botPick]);
}

$("#playerDiscard").text(playerDiscard.length);
$("#playerDraw").text(player.length);
```

Why is my alert happening before my image is reflected on the page?

Comment: probably because it takes time to load in the image - you should preload it so it gets cached

Comment: That's because the `.css` function is asynchrounous (it will return immediately)

Comment: Put some time delay in your code because image take some time to fetch so your alert box execute before image load.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal a delay won't do the trick, because you can't know how long it takes to load the image.

Comment: Use load() `$(window).load(function() {` to wait element to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery.css()` function is asynchronous. It will return immediately, so not when the image is loaded.

Create a "dummy" image to preload it and use the `onload` event to determine when the image is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var imgUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
    var $img = $("<img />");
    $img.on("load", function() {
        $("#yourImage").css("background-image", "url("+ imgUrl +")");
        alert("image is loaded");
    });
    $img.attr("src", imgUrl);
});
```